# Install Ubuntu to SSD On Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, ssd

I have a new SSD and I want to make a fresh installation of Ubuntu on it (so I can replace my existing SATA connected SSD on my computer).

Is there a way I could do that from my existing ubuntu computer? I am able to connect the SSD to the computer (via sata-to-USB cable).

I have installed VirtualBox and tried to "play with the settings", but I can't figure out if it's possible.

Comment: In principle, you can use virtualbox to install Ubuntu into the SSD. But using the normal method for installation would be much simpler.

Comment: installing ubuntu with the normal method is not an issue for me... but i thought it would be good to know how to do something like that on a working computer... there are parts of the normal installation that is like "watching pain dry" so at that point i could just put the installation to the background.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Use your existing operating system (on the SATA hard drive) to create a live USB of Ubuntu. [Here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) is the official tutorial to create a live USB in Ubuntu.

Now, replace the hard drive with the SSD and boot with the live USB. Then, [install](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) Ubuntu from scratch into the SSD.

Comment: maybe my questions wasn't clear enough... i want to install the ubuntu OS while i am already booted on my existing ubuntu installation. this is so that i can continue to use my existing installation. i was hoping for there to be a solution where i could install ubuntu to a physical SSD from something like virtualbox.